# Displaying Page Load Time On Webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the loading time of a webpage on site. I can get this working by writing to console.log but writing the information to a page is beyond me.

In my head I have

```
<!-- Loading Time -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
</script>
```

Then I have this to write to the console log

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime / 1000);
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly but I really want to display the loading time on a webpage. How do I achieve this? My page is a simple html / css site.

Comment: How do you want to display it? Where do you want do display it? What is the problem, I don't see you trying it anywhere but console log that you say it is working? Include your HTML and CSS, make [mre] using snipet of your attempt.

Comment: I'd suggest you start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the time you calculated into an element of the webpage using the [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_node_innertext.asp) property of a [`Node`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/dom_obj_all.asp).

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    console.log('Page load time is ' + loadTime / 1000);
    performanceDisplay = document.getElementById("performance-display") // get a reference to the paragraph
    performanceDisplay.innerText = loadTime / 1000 // put the value of the variable loadTime into the paragraph
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="performance-display"></p>
</body>
```

Or, if you do not want to put the paragraph manually into the HTML, you can create it in the JavaScript using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    console.log('Page load time is ' + loadTime / 1000);

    performanceDisplay = document.createElement("p") // create a new paragraph element
    performanceDisplay.innerText = loadTime / 1000 // put the value of the variable loadTime into the paragraph
    document.body.appendChild(performanceDisplay) // add the paragraph element to the body of the document
}
```

Comment: Thank you for everyone's answers It's much easier to understand for me seeing a working example. I dressed this up in some CSS and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Three possible methods are:

1. Just writing to the document directly (should not be used because of the reasons [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)):

   `document.write(loadTime);`
2. Adding an HTML element and setting its inner text to loadTime:

```js
function displayLoadtime(loadtime){
  document.getElementById("loading-time").innerText = loadtime;
}
```

```html
<p id='loading-time'>Loading...</p>
```

3. Creating the element in Javascript and displaying the loadTime using it:

```js
function displayLoadingtime(loadtime){
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = loadtime;
  document.getElementById("loading-time-container").appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id='loading-time-container'></div>
```

I know what I answered is some beginners' stuff and you probably know it, but I will edit the answer in case you give more details, because I don't see any problems in displaying it if you already have the loadTime.

Comment: By the way, I haven't added the part of passing the actual loading time to the functions, because I assume you know how to pass parameters to functions and all this very basic stuff, I just illustrated the methods for dynamically showing content in webpage.

Comment: `document.write` [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @Programmer you're right, but I just added it to let him know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Rylad!

You can easily put it into your webpage by referencing an HTML element.

Ie. add an element with the id `timeContainer` to your page and set its `innerHTML` to your variable, `loadTime`. Here's an example:

```html
<body>
  <span id="timeContainer">
    The load time will be displayed here when the page is finished loading
  </span>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
      console.log(loadTime)
      
      document.getElementById("timeContainer").innerText = loadTime;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This gives you a really crazy output. In my console log, the time is 0.709 but on the page, your script gives the output as -1612638473152

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, @Rylad! I forgot to wrap the function in an `onload` event. I just copied the first of your code snippets.

I updated the code, and it should now run properly. You can also divide it by 1000 to get seconds, as you did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Simple way to get loading time

```
<body>
    <span id="loadingTime"></span>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
            let timestemp = new Date(e.timeStamp).getTime()
            console.log('loading time is', timestemp)
            document.getElementById('loadingTime').innerText = "loading time is "+timestemp
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).